# What kind of catastrophe could wipe out a country's human population without harming its ecosystems?

Tags: science-fiction, alternate-history

In the backstory of my universe, China ceased to exist as a country sometime around the 2010s as a result of the CCP trying to meddle with alien technology in an attempt to accelerate its efforts at achieving global hegemony. No prizes for guessing how well that turned out, as the CCP somehow ended up making China's 1 billion strong population perish in a short amount of time by pure accident, which permanently ruined China's chances at becoming a global superpower and significantly shifted the balance of geopolitical power.

However, a curious trait about this cataclysm is that while humans died left and right, China's ecosystems stayed intact and even flourished after the Chinese population vanished, as nature has reclaimed many human settlements.

The only problem is that I can't think of a disaster that could do all of the above.

**What kind of catastrophe could fit the bill?**

---

Comment: The hard part is not finding something to kill off ll the Chinese. The hard part is finding something that will kill all the Chinese *and nobody else!* Your killer has to somehow....judge a person's nationality?

Comment: This is a story based question. Especially since you are dealing with alien technology you can decide pretty much anything. Nanomachines first come to mind but is just one option among many. As is the question is going to be closed am afraid.

Comment: @PcMan Indeed, how does the 'catastrophe' select its victims? Will it happen in Taiwan too? They are not part of PRC but 100% Chinese from every other point of view.

Comment: Borders are human concepts. Only humans care about borders, and nothing else. And humans are very much part of the ecosystem(s); it's nonsensical to kill all humans and say that *"ecosystems stayed intact"*. For example, if all humans die I strongly suspect that rice and sorghum populations will be greatly affected too.

Comment: Obligatory vaccine to chinese population that is actually a poison. It's not that it don't kill other it's just i wasn't administered o others.

Comment: I think the killer has to  judge the person's geography. It should kill non-Chinese who happen to be vacationing there. So it's not viral, at least. But anything that could do it thoroughly, will of course, kill other organisms in the region. Even if it affects neurology, pretty much the only animal life that will survive will be rotifers and paramecia. Really this is looking for a physics answer.

Comment: Maybe if the question was phrased as "all human life in eastern asia", or something similar? With the designated group being "Chinese" we cannot even ask for a targeted genetic plague, as "chinese" comprises some 56 distinct ethnic groups, many of whom occur outside of China, the country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Chinese are taken by their alien phones.**

The alien tech is incorporated into smart phones which the Party issues to everyone.  There are a lot of benefits to these new phones but one of the coolest things is limited teleportation: people can use their phones to hop from where they are to a number of "jump sites".  This is going to be the economic miracle - moving goods and persons without needing so much fuel or infrastructure.

One day everyone with an alien-enhanced phone disappears.  Small children and very old people are who is left.

The nice thing about this is you sidestep the panic, and the dying, and the refugees.  More of a Rapture type thing.  Perfect for a backstory mentioned in passing.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your plot allows for a small number of refugees and chinese people living abroad to survive.

**Large-scale economy failure.**

For a similar (bad, but not catastrophic) event, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Pests_Campaign)

Those 1 bilion people need to eat almost every day in order to survive.

It is possible that the China rulers invest every resource they can put their hands on, in a bid to get a maximum positive effect (or profit, whatever) of the new technology. Then they fail and the country is left without a means to survive to the next harvest time.

The social order collapses, the world admits as many refugees as at all possible, maybe some more, fights the rest of them and all this ends up as less than 1/10 of the initial population. Most of the survivors don't like the idea of returning to the bad land in principle, those who try, mostly fail.

The rest of the world imposes heavy represion on anyone trying to resurrect the CCP.

p.s. Chinese, when a generation or two away from the CCP, are not that bad people, are they?

Answer (score 0):

A bioweapon.

Think of covid but capable of killing every one infected. You will also have to make the international community actually be capable of containing the virus by quarantining the whole country or something like that.

Even if you want to add a survival rate, killing 9 out of 10 is probably enough to make the government collapse. Keep in mind that a lot more people would die due starvation since the economy and food production will certainly collapse as well.

Comment: If we redid covid to have a 100% fatality rate it wouldn't be enough. This would definitely wipe out many countries and governments; USA, Europe, South America, Africa - all basically gone. But look at Oceana and southeast Asia - Vanuatu would've had a single death (first case was in quarantine on Nov 11). Vietnam would have ~1,300 deaths. My state (South Australia) would have had ~550 deaths from a population of 1.7 million. However, if you crank covid up in a second way as well -  have a very long symptom-free period (like - a month), you may be able to achieve the OP's human-free world.

Answer (score 0):

#### No one wants children - everyone is on birth control

A society with a strong belief in personal freedoms, with the ability to control one's life, could easily go extinct inadvertently if nobody wanted to have children, and the means to stop reproducing (sex ed, contraception and abortion) are available.

All you'd need to do is create societal or economic pressures on young women to not reproduce:

- Encourage people to party in their 20s, 30s, and 40s. Use movies ands TV shows to glamourise youthfull adventures on the town right up until middle age, and show motherhood as an endless parade of dirty nappies, lost sleep, and missed social events.
- Make the cost of living so expensive that 2 full time incomes are needed to sustain minimum standards of living for 2 adults.
- Have an impending environmental apocalypse that's so bad nobody wants to bring a kid into it.
- Ensure that young families get zero or miniscule government support in order to punish them for having children.
- Make the cost of a days childcare equal to a days earnings to ensure that those who have children never leave poverty.
- Encourage women to build a career first, and delay having children until they're well off, and then set wages low enough that they're not out of poverty until long past menopause.

Answer (score 0):

A highly-contagious, possibly life-threatening plague. The disease will have to be only detrimental to the health of human beings, and other fauna can be asymptomatic carriers. The fish in the rivers and lakes, the trees in the forests, the birds nesting on perches, etc. would not be affected, but the humans will. Especially if there's a low trust for science, and thus, people don't take proper precautions, turning an easily-contained epidemic into a catastrophe. As for the people who have the brains and conscience to play it safe, the economy will be sent into disrepair, and an economic collapse will screw over the survivors.

And that will too only affect the humans negatively. Because bears don't care that their not meeting minimum wage, the bees don't find their bank accounts frozen, and wolf alphas don't have to lay off the other wolves when they run out of money. Because the wildlife don't need, and don't care about money, they will be OK while everything goes to hell for the humans.